# Unshrink text permanently in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

When I use LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu 20.04, I am not able to expand a paragraph so that it looks always like this :

[image]

Instead, it always looks like this with the little arrow on the right :

[image]

I would like it stays unwrap permanently as in the first picture.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a feature like that. I mean, what would happen if every cell had text like this in it? It would overlap and be unreadable. Resizing the cell is not an option?

Comment: I tried, but I have always the same problem. There is just more space and the text doesn't want to take that empty space

Comment: If you just want a better view for editing, you can expand the input line. This should stay that way for the entire session and when you select a cell you get the full text.

Comment: Reagrding the space: have you enabled line breaks on that cell?

Comment: This is in LibreCalc, specifically?

Comment: @roaima Yes, it is LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: You are mis-understanding the display (or I am mis-understanding the screenshot you gave): It is _**NOT**_ expanding the paragraph. It is showing you the full paragraph in a _**tooltip**_ while you hover the mouse. The actual data that is put in the tooltip has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear in what is it that you mean to get. I am not aware of any way to control text **outside** of the cell borders, much less permanently.

However, in LibreOffice you can force that the text fits the cell border by limiting text on the right and expanding the vertical size. It is in `Format` --> `WrapText`.

Then resize the cell to meet your needs.

Note that the "little arrow" on the right only appears when that cell **also** contains some text (or value). To indicate that the previous cell ends there (and the next one is being shown) the "little arrow" appears. Erasing the contents of the cell at the right allows a longer text to be shown. Is this your problem?

Comment: Yes, but is doesn't work permanently. If I close it and reopen it, it still shrinks as the second picture in the question.

Comment: Did you stored it in the disk ? ( a.k.a. `Save`  a.k.a. `Ctrl-S`) @notaprogrammertoday

Comment: Yes, I did it .

Comment: Is then your problem when you select the cell to **edit** it ?  Or, is it because some cell at the right contains some text (or, maybe an "empty" value) ?? @notaprogrammertoday

Comment: No it is not my problem as well

Comment: If you formated a cell as you wanted and stored the worksheet, the next open **must** have the same format. If it is true that that didn't work, then the problem **must** be something else. Rejecting every other option leaves nothing to help you with. Sorry you can not explain your problem. @notaprogrammertoday

Comment: As well as resizing a single cell, you can also select multiple cells (both horizontally & vertically) and then use `Merge Cells` from the right-click menu (or Format -> Merge Cells -> Merge Cells).    I often use `Wrap Text` with `Merge Cells` in LO Calc to make sure that a large text block is displayed correctly.